# FileZilla and FreeCommander run as background process and never displays after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-10, filezilla, freecommander

I’ve upgraded to Windows 10. Initially Oracle VM VirtualBox wouldn’t load - I reinstalled it and problem solved. However, the same thing is happening with FileZilla. I upgraded to the latest version. When I try to start it, it shows up in Task Manager under Background Processes, but never loads the user interface. The same thing is happening with FreeCommander.

Comment: I have the same issue here, but with other desktop applications.